# how to validate HTML5 (e.g. unclosed <p> tags)

Tags: html, validation

I'm used to teaching others about the importance of writing good html code, by forcing them to use the http://validator.w3.org for checking if they forgot to close a tag.

This works great when using xHTML1 Strict, but I'd like to use the HTML5 doctype and tags where possible.

The validator does not report opening a `<p>` tag without closing it to be an error.

Is this normal in HTML5 or is the validator not working properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The validator is likely working correctly:

> A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

From: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't seem to help good coding practices though, not closing a paragraph tag will mess up in different browsers, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Validator.nu will provide HTML5 validation, you can read more about it here http://about.validator.nu/

Answer (score 0):

I just found this which does exactly what you're asking… better late than never!

http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder

I've also used tidy and an xml editor in Windows, but those are really old (don't understand html5), and I'm not running web dev on windows anymore, only Mac/Linux.